# What is the FROC (free-response receiver operating characteristic) curve?

Tags: deep-learning, roc, model-evaluation

I've found it in [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-14148-0_1) paper but can't find any publicly available definition of it. There, it is used to evaluate the performance of aggregate CNNs.